# Analytics to get the data regarding drop off

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, analytics

I am using google analytics in my website. While improving my website I want more details like -  from which page the uses are dropping off. For example they are going to the registration page and then actually they are not registering and leaving from there only. Or most users are not reaching the registration page itself. In short my requirement is to get the data about from which step/page the users are giving up in the flow.

I have analysed the data getting from google analytics but didn't found. Is there anything available in the google analytics or any other analytics framework available that suitable to my requirement for Python/Django website.

Comment: Behavior->Site Content->Exit Pages, or ga:exitPagePath in the API might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Eike's answer, you might also want to check out the *Behavior > [Behavior Flow](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2785577?hl=en)* section of Google Analytics. It will draw on screen the flow through which Users navigate on your site, including drop-off metrics to help you analyze where your users Exit.

Alternatively, you might also want to set up [Goals](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en) for your most important actions, like User Registration. You will then be able to view a Funnel of your micro-conversions, helping you understand where your Users might be abandoning their actions.